# Nested foreach loop changing values in a dataframe R

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am trying to convert two nested for loops to two nested foreach loops to change values of a dataframe based on matching prerequisites.  Reason being I believe I can speed up the process significantly.  Below is an example of my code:

```
 library(foreach) # for loop to parallelize
 library(doMC) # create the number of cores to use

 # set the number of cores to use
 registerDoMC(22)  # number of CPU cores

 file_list <- c("a", "b", "c")
 ldf <- c(data.frame(Date = c("2016-10-01", "2016-10-02", "2016-10-03", "2016-10-04")),
     data.frame(Date = c("2016-10-07", "2016-10-08", "2016-10-09")),
     data.frame(Date = c("2016-10-15", "2016-10-16", "2016-10-17", "2016-10-18", "2016-10-19")))

 DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.POSIXct("2016-10-01", tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct("2016-10-31", tz = "UTC"), by = 'day'),
             A = 0,
             B = 0,
             C = 0)

 DF2 <- DF # DF2 is used to compare my attempt result


 for (i in 1:length(file_list))
 {
   Date <- ldf[[i]]
   Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, tz = "UTC")

   for (j in 1:length(Date))
   {
     ROW <- which(DF$Date == Date[j])
     DF[ROW,i+1] <- 1
   }

 }

 throwaway <- foreach (i = 1:length(file_list)) %dopar%
 {
   Date <- ldf[[i]]
   Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, tz = "UTC")

   foreach (j = 1:length(Date)) %do%
   {
     ROW <- which(DF2$Date == Date[j])
     DF2[ROW,i+1] <- 1
     return(NULL)
   }
 }
```

`filelist` is a list of files that I am reading in

`ldf` is the variable used to store the files that are read

These two variables are made up in this example, just to have a reproducible example.

`DF` is where I am going to store the changes in the values made by the `foreach` loops

`DF2` is my attempted try and where it is stored

The output I am looking for is that of `DF`, but `DF2` remains unchanged.  I understand foreach loops are designed for their return values, but how can I get the return values to match with the locations of where the values of the dataframe should change.  These values are where the date of each file read in `file_list` match with the dates in the dataframe `DF2`.  If they match, then a 1 is placed in that particular location of row (Date) and column (Filename). Thanks in advance for any help!

Desired output is:

```
 > DF
          Date A B C
 1  2016-10-01 1 0 0
 2  2016-10-02 1 0 0
 3  2016-10-03 1 0 0
 4  2016-10-04 1 0 0
 5  2016-10-05 0 0 0
 6  2016-10-06 0 0 0
 7  2016-10-07 0 1 0
 8  2016-10-08 0 1 0
 9  2016-10-09 0 1 0
 10 2016-10-10 0 0 0
 11 2016-10-11 0 0 0
 12 2016-10-12 0 0 0
 13 2016-10-13 0 0 0
 14 2016-10-14 0 0 0
 15 2016-10-15 0 0 1
 16 2016-10-16 0 0 1
 17 2016-10-17 0 0 1
 18 2016-10-18 0 0 1
 19 2016-10-19 0 0 1
 20 2016-10-20 0 0 0
 21 2016-10-21 0 0 0
 22 2016-10-22 0 0 0
 23 2016-10-23 0 0 0
 24 2016-10-24 0 0 0
 25 2016-10-25 0 0 0
 26 2016-10-26 0 0 0
 27 2016-10-27 0 0 0
 28 2016-10-28 0 0 0
 29 2016-10-29 0 0 0
 30 2016-10-30 0 0 0
 31 2016-10-31 0 0 0
```

Comment: Could you explain this part: "get the return values to match with the locations of where the values of the dataframe should change. "? Maybe you can give an example of your desired result?

Comment: Of course! These values that I am looking for are where the date of each file read in `file_list` match with the dates in the dataframe `DF2`.  If they match, then a 1 is placed in that particular location of row (Date) and column (Filename).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using zero loops but a `Reduce()` with `merge` across all df items of the dataframe list. However, you need to set up your data frames and list slightly different.

First, add as the first elmenet of list the sequential `Date` dataframe. Then, in each file you read in add a second column corresponding to `A`, `B`, `C` with each equal to one (which can be done in the `lapply` or `for` loop used in read in process -post this part for demonstration). Altogether, as shown below with `all.equal` an exact match results with original DF:

```
# INITIALIZE LIST WITH DATE SEQUENCE DF
newldf <- list(data.frame(Date = as.factor(seq(as.POSIXct("2016-10-01", tz = "UTC"), 
                                  as.POSIXct("2016-10-31", tz = "UTC"), 
                                  by = 'day'))))

# APPEND LIST OF DATA FRAMES THAT ARE READ IN, EACH WITH SECOND COL = 1
newldf <- append(newldf,
                list(data.frame(Date = c("2016-10-01", "2016-10-02", 
                                         "2016-10-03", "2016-10-04"), A = 1),
                     data.frame(Date = c("2016-10-07", "2016-10-08", 
                                         "2016-10-09"), B = 1),
                     data.frame(Date = c("2016-10-15", "2016-10-16", 
                                         "2016-10-17", "2016-10-18", "2016-10-19"), C=1)))

# MERGE ALL DATA FAMES TOGETHER
newDF <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by=c("Date"), all=T), newldf)
newDF[is.na(newDF)] <- 0                                # CONVERT NAs TO ZEROs
newDF$Date <- as.POSIXct(newDF$Date, tz = "UTC")        # CONVERT DATE TO POSIXct
str(newDF)
# 'data.frame': 31 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ Date: POSIXct, format: "2016-10-01" "2016-10-02" ...
#  $ A   : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ B   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
#  $ C   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

str(DF)
# 'data.frame': 31 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ Date: POSIXct, format: "2016-10-01" "2016-10-02" ...
#  $ A   : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ B   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
#  $ C   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

all.equal(DF, newDF)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: looks very promising!  However, what would you suggest if the Dates you're appending are not the same length?  That's what I am working with and unfortunately, the appending process breaks at that point. I've updated my list in my original answer and the end goal to reflect this.  My apologies for not thinking straight and putting the same quantities of dates.

Comment: Merge here uses `all=T` argument or basically an outer join, so lengths of individual dataframes in list can vary without an issue. I updated the list with your unequal lengths and ran without an error. Not sure what you mean about breaking.

Comment: My apologies!  One of my data files had no values and the append function would break.  I was successfully able to replicate your solution.  Thank you for all your help!